# Eclipse Luna file names not shown in GIT Commit Changes dialogue

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I've recently updated to Eclipse Luna standard on Linux Mint. There seem to be a few bugs with it which I've managed to work around, except for when I'm committing changes with Git.

The "Commit Changes" dialog comes up as expected, but the files window shows only a list of file icons ***without*** file names. Has anyone else seen this and know how to fix it?

I've tried upgrading to the latest eGit, but that hasn't helped.

I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem on google.

Comment: Could you include a screen shot? That sounds like a theming problem to me.

Comment: I have the same problem with Ecplise Luna and the out of the box git plugin. I change a single file, I see the changed file in `git status` but when trying to commit in Ecplise, the commit window is empty.

Comment: same problem here.... very often 1 file is missing in view. after commit & push the file is however displayed in changeset. seems to be a pure presentation issue.

Comment: Same problem. A solution is published here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/796457/

Answer (score 7):

From https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/796457/, a solution has been published to force a different GTK mode:

```
SWT_GTK3=0 eclipse
```

If it works, a permanent option:
You can add the following lines to `eclipse.ini` to make it permanent

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Source: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=115477

Comment: Works for me at least.